# What is default CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN used for Spring Boot logging and where to find it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback, slf4j

The Spring Boot reference documentation [4.6. Custom Log Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-custom-log-configuration) states about the default system properties representing a default logging pattern to use on the console (only supported with the default Logback setup).

- Spring Environment: `logging.pattern.console`
- System Property: `CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN`

I guess the default log line look is familiar for all the Spring Boot framework users:

```
2020-08-04 12:00:00.000  INFO 24568 --- [           main] c.c.MyWonderfulSpringApplication          : The following profiles are active: local
```

As long as I want to take look on how it looks and get inspired for defining my own one, where can I find this default value for a currently used version of Spring Boot?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I have just found out this configuration is available at the [`DefaultLogbackConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/DefaultLogbackConfiguration.java) file under Spring Boot project:

```
private static final String CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN = "%clr(%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}}){faint} "
            + "%clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} "
            + "%clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} "
            + "%clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}";
```

To find the pattern for a certain Spring Boot version, either:

- Browse the source file available at GitHub: [Spring Boot 2.3.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.3.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/DefaultLogbackConfiguration.java).
- In IntelliJ Idea press 2x <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> and search in the `Classes` tab for `DefaultLogbackConfiguration`.

The source of my findings is https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/logging-console-pattern.html.

---

**Edit:** The default Logback console logger configuration (for example setting the logger to the `DEBUG` level) can be overridden as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Here's the full string without being split up: `%clr(%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}`

Answer (score 12):

If you are using `logback-spring.xml`, then adding the following to your xml would automatically pick up spring's default logback configuration for console appender.

```html
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>
```

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/howto.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging

Comment: You are a lifesaver!